# Mongodb: Get sample of nested array using Aggreagate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

[$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) allows me to get a slice of nested array. I used it successfully like this:

```
const user = await User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId(user_id) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { friends: "$friends" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$friends"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "profile",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "profile",
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "profile.online": true,
          },
        },

        {
          $project: {
            name: "$name",
            surname: "$surname",
            profile: { $arrayElemAt: ["$profile", 0] },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "friends",
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friends: {
        $slice: ["$friends", skip, limit],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Now, instead of taking a slice, I would like to take a random sample of the array field `friends`.

I could not find a way to do this. But, in the group stage I can use something like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/):

```
  const pipeline = [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "profiles",
        let: { profiles_id: "$profile" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              online: true,
              $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$profiles_id"] },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "profile",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    { $sample: { size: 10 } },
  ];
  const users = await User.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last `$addFields` stage to this.

Pros:  It "works."

Cons:  You are not guaranteed *unique* random entries in the list.  To get that is a lot more work.  If you have a LOT more friends than the range then you are probably OK.

```js
    ,{$addFields: {friends: {$reduce: { // overwrite friends array...
        // $range is the number of things you want to pick:                                            
        input: {$range:[0,4]},
        initialValue: [],
        in: {
            $let: {
                // qq will be a random # between 0 and size-1 thanks to mult                           
                // and floor, so we do not have to do qq-1 to get to zero-based                        
                // indexing on the $friends array                                                      
                vars: {qq: {$floor:{$multiply:[{$rand: {}},{$size:"$friends"}]}} },

                // $concat only works for strings, but $concatArrays can be used                       
                // (creatively) on other types. Here $slice returns an array of                        
                // 1 item which we easily pass to $concatArrays to build the                           
                // the overall result:                                                                 
                in: {$concatArrays: [ "$$value", {$slice:["$friends","$$qq",1]} ]}
            }}
    }}
```

**UPDATED**

This version exploits keeping state in the `$reduce` chain and will not pick dupes.  It does so by iteratively shrinking the input candidate list of items as each item is randomly chosen.  The output is a little nested (i.e. `friends` is not set to picked random sample but rather to an *object* containing picks and the remnant aa list) but this is something easily reformatted after the fact.  In MongoDB 5.0 we could finish it off with:

```
    {$addFields: {friends: {$getField: {field: "$friends.picks", input: {$reduce: {
```

but many people are not yet on 5.0.

```
    {$addFields: {friends: {$reduce: {
        // $range is the number of things you want to pick:
        input: {$range:[0,6]},

        // This is classic use of $reduce to iterate over something AND
        // preserve state.  We start with picks as empty and aa being the
        // original friends array:
        initialValue: {aa: "$friends", picks: []},

        in: {
            $let: {
                // idx will be a random # between 0 and size-1 thanks to mult
                // and floor, so we do not have to do idx-1 to get to zero-based
                // indexing on the $friends array.  idx and sz will be eval'd
                // each time reduce turns the crank through the input range:
                vars: {idx: {$floor:{$multiply:[{$rand: {}},{$size:"$$value.aa"}]}},
                       // cannot set sz and then use it in same vars; oh well
                       sz: {$size:"$$value.aa"}
                      },

                in: {
                    // Add to our picks list:
                    picks: {$concatArrays: [ "$$value.picks", {$slice:["$$value.aa","$$idx",1]} ]},

                    // And now shrink up the input candidate array.                                    
                    // Sadly, we cannot do $slice:[array,pos,0] to yield an empty
                    // array and keep the $concat logic tight; thus we have to test
                    // for front and end special conditions.
                    // This whole bit is to extract the chosen item from the aa
                    // array by splicing together a new one MINUS the target.
                    // This will change the value of $sz (-1) as we crank thru
                    // the picks.  This ensures we only pick UNPICKED items from
                    // $$value.aa!
                    
                    aa: {$cond: [{$eq:["$$idx",0]}, // if

                         // idx 0: Take from idx 1 and count size - 1:
                         {$slice:["$$value.aa",1,{$subtract:["$$sz",1]}]}, // then

                         // idx last: Take from idx 0 and ALSO count size - 1:
                         {$cond: [ // else
                             {$eq:["$$idx",{$subtract:["$$sz",1]}]}, // if
                             {$slice:["$$value.aa",0,{$subtract:["$$sz",1]}]}, // then

                             // else not 0 or last item, i.e. idx = 3
                             {$concatArrays: [
                                 // Start at 0, count idx; this will land
                                 // us BEFORE the target item (because idx
                                 // is n-1:
                                 {$slice:["$$value.aa",0,"$$idx"]},

                                 // Jump over the target (+1), and go n-2
                                 // (1 for idx/n conversion, and 1 for the
                                 // fact we jumped over:
                                 {$slice:["$$value.aa",{$add:["$$idx",1]},{$subtract:["$$sz",2]}]}
                             ]}
                         ]}
                    ]}
                }
            }}
        }}
    }}

]);
```

Starting in MongoDB v4.4 (Jan 2021), you may opt to use the `$function` operator.  The `splice` function in javascript does all the work of the multiple `$slice` operations in the previous example.

```js
    {$addFields: {friends: {$function: {
        body: function(candidates, npicks) {
            var picks = []
            for(var i = 0; i < npicks; i++) {
                var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * candidates.length);
                picks.push(candidates.splice(idx,1)[0]);
            }
            return picks;
        },
        args: [ "$friends", 4], // 4 is num to pick                                                    
        lang: "js"
    }}
```